# Composite primary key in multi-tenant SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-sql-database

I'm building a multi-tenant app (single database, single schema) using ASP.NET Web Api, Entity Framework and SQL Server / Azure database.

This app will be used by 1000-5000 customers. All the tables will have a `TenantId` (`Guid`) column. Right now, I use single column primary key which is `Id` (`Guid`).

The problem with that is, I have to check if the data supplied by the user is from / for the right tenant. E.g I have a sales order table which has a `CustomerId` column. Everytime user post/update sales order, I have to check if the `CustomerId` is from the same tenant.

It gets worse because each tenant might have several outlets. Then I have to check TenantId and OutletId. It's really a maintenance nightmare and bad for performance.

I'm thinking to add `TenantId` as primary key along with `Id`. And possibly add `OutletId` too. So primary key in sales order table will have multiple columns, `Id`, `TenantId`, `OutletId`.

What is the downside of this approach? Would the performance hurt badly using composite key? Does the composite key order matter? Are there better solution for my problem?

Comment: Just to be clear: any table can have **exactly one** primary key - never more than one. That primary key *might* consist of multiple columns - but it's still just **one** primary key

Comment: Could you please explain the question in better way? What is the relation between tenant, customer, outlet, sales, etc. It is little difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm developing a point-of-sale application. Tenant is the customer who buys my product. Each tenant has one or more shops/outlets. Each tenant sells things to his customers. Hope that clears my question

Comment: @marc_s noted. I've updated my question. sorry for my english

Comment: Reynaldi você usa GUID na chave primária turnê? O que o desempenho? Eu estou tenho uma tabela com 20 millions linha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to use a composite key please use always (if possible) all elements of the key to avoid [index range scans](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/posts/11379/sql-server-t-sql-best-practice-composite-primary-keys-performance-and-accuracy-impact.aspx)
2. The order of elements is important. If you want to retrieve for example all data related to a single tenant (see pt. 1) you should use `TenantId` as the first element (see [Why does primary key order matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713233/why-does-primary-key-order-matter))
3. For Azure SQL you should also consider concepts like [Elastic Scale](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction/) or partitioning for legacy systems which could improve performance.
4. Do you really need a guid for the TenantId? If you have a limited amount of customers (<= 5000 is not that much) you could also use a int (or even int64) type which would allow easier partitioning (see pt. 3)... I do like guids a lot, but for ease of maintenance and if I do not need the big range for data I try to avoid them (see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2010/05/27/guid-vs-int-debate.aspx) for performance). If you need the tenant id in advance, you can use sequences (a new feature for SQL Azure V12):

   ```
   create sequence CustomerSequence as int
        start with 0
        increment by 1;
   select next value for CustomerSequence;
   ```

**EDIT:** Added information about sequences in SQL Azure

Comment: Yes, i think its better to use integer for the tenantId field for performance. I use guid because it is more convenient. Because when i add tenant, i also need to add other data to other tables. With guid i can instantly get the value, while in identity field i have to wait after the changes is saved. Do you have an idea how to handle that?

Comment: For the last update of SQL Azure you can use sequences: `create sequence CustomerSequence as int
    start with 0
    increment by 1` and `select next value for CustomerSequence`